# Hilos múltiples para varias llamadas GET a URLs en Go

Tags: http, go

Estoy tratando de desarrollar en Go una API que devuelva los postes de autobús que siguen operativos para luego mandarlos a una base de datos. El número de postes va desde `0` a `1500`, por lo que tengo que ir preguntando a cada poste su estado, y el HTTP devuelve un `200` o un `500`, pero el caso es que intento hacerlo con *threads*, de forma que se hagan llamadas a la URL de forma simultánea, ya que de forma secuencial tarda 16 minutos hacer todas las llamadas.

He partido de la base de la primera función que está comentada, pero no sé cómo separar eso en hilos, ya que llevo poco tiempo con *Go*.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)
var i int = 0
var convStr string
var message = make(chan string)

/*func main(){
    for i = 0; i < 1500; i++ {
        z = strconv.Itoa(i)
        url := "http://www.urbanosdezaragoza.es/frm_esquemaparadatime.php?poste=" + z
        resp, err := http.Get(url)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Houston, we've got problems")
        }else{
            if resp.StatusCode == 200{
                fmt.Println("OK: El poste "+z+" existe")
            }else{
                fmt.Println("WARN: El poste "+z+" NO existe")
            }
        }
    }
}*/

//Return 2 houndred posts
func returnTH(c chan string){
 for i = 0; i < 200; i++ {  
    convStr = strconv.Itoa(i)
    url := "http://www.urbanosdezaragoza.es/frm_esquemaparadatime.php?poste=" + convStr
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Houston, we've got problems")
    }else{
        if resp.StatusCode == 200{
            //fmt.Println("OK: El poste "+z+" existe")
            c <- "OK: The bus post "+convStr+" exists"
        }else{
            //fmt.Println("WARN: El poste "+z+" NO existe")
            c <- "WARN: The bus post "+convStr+" does not exist"
        }      
    }
  } 
}
func returnFH(z chan string){
  for i = 201; i < 400; i++ {   
   convStr = strconv.Itoa(i)
   url := "http://www.urbanosdezaragoza.es/frm_esquemaparadatime.php?poste=" + convStr
   resp, err := http.Get(url)
   if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Houston, we've got problems")
   }else{
       if resp.StatusCode == 200{
           //fmt.Println("OK: El poste "+z+" existe")
           z <- "OK: The bus post "+convStr+" exists"
       }else{
           //fmt.Println("WARN: El poste "+z+" NO existe")
           z <- "WARN: The bus post "+convStr+" does not exist"
       }   
   } 
 }
}

func threadPrint(c, z chan string){
   for {
       threadOne := <- c
       threadTwo := <- z
       fmt.Println(threadOne)
       fmt.Println(threadTwo)
   }
}
func main(){
    start := time.Now()
    var c chan string = make(chan string)
    var z chan string = make(chan string)
    //for i = 0; i < 1500; i++{
    go returnTH(c)
    go returnFH(z)
    go threadPrint(c,z)
    /*go getBusPostStatus(400, 600)
    go getBusPostStatus(600, 800)
    go getBusPostStatus(800, 1000)
    go getBusPostStatus(1000, 1200)
    go getBusPostStatus(1200, 1400)
    go getBusPostStatus(1400, 1500)*/
    //}
    timeExec:= time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println("Time to exec code = ", timeExec)

    /*var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
    fmt.Println("done")*/
}
```

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque está en inglés.

Comment: Perdonad por la pregunta aquí, no era mi intención,  en realidad iba dirigida al StackOverflow generico pero no se porque me la mando por aquí... Solo era que no sabía como separar en threads para que hiciera 1500 peticiones URL a una pagina para que devolviera las cabeceras HTTP de estado.

Comment: Haz la traducción correspondiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo funcional que resuelve tu problema usando múltiples goroutinas a la vez. Tu lo llamas hilos pero en Go **no hay hilos**.

Este problema es un ejemplo típico del **patrón productor-consumidor**, concretamente he usado el *"sabor"* `N-productores : 1-consumidor`.

Básicamente hay que lanzar N workers o productores (`N < 1500`, en mi caso `N=15`) que realizan una tarea (una petición HTTP cada uno) y luego se recolectan/agrupan los resultados.

> Consultadas 1500 paradas en 2m29.1121255s

Aumentar el número de workers ayudará a hacer este tiempo menor aunque solo hasta cierto punto. El tiempo de respuesta de los servidores de `www.urbanosdezaragoza.es` también influye.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

// Work define un "item de trabajo" que va a ser procesado por un worker.
type Work struct {
    Client *http.Client
    Number int
}

// Result define el resultado de un "item de trabajo" después de ser procesado
// por un worker.
type Result struct {
    Error      error
    StatusCode int
    Number     int
}

// worker se coordina mediante un WaitGroup (wg) y utiliza dos canales para
// operar con datos. Un canal es de entrada (in) y el otro es de salida (out).
//
// Cada canal funciona con un tipo diferente de datos porque no necesariamente
// los datos de entrada y los de salida tienen que ser iguales.
func worker(wg *sync.WaitGroup, in chan Work, out chan Result) {
    for w := range in {
        destination := fmt.Sprintf("http://www.urbanosdezaragoza.es/frm_esquemaparadatime.php?poste=%d", w.Number)

        // Ignoro explicitamente el error de NewRequest porque en principio
        // nunca va a darse, lo suyo sería tratarlo.
        req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", destination, nil)

        // http.Get !
        resp, err := w.Client.Do(req)

        // Se podría sacar la declaración de `res` fuera del bucle para
        // reutilizar memoria, lo dejo como ejercicio para quien pueda estar
        // interesado.
        res := Result{Number: w.Number}

        // No interesa parar Hacer print del error no sirve de nada cuando los errores se empiezan
        // a acumular.
        if err != nil {
            res.Error = err
            log.Printf("HTTP ERR poste=%d", w.Number, err)
        } else {
            res.StatusCode = resp.StatusCode
            log.Printf("HTTP OK poste=%d StatusCode=%d", w.Number, resp.StatusCode)
        }

        out <- res
    }

    wg.Done()
}

func consumir(out chan Result) {
    for res := range out {
        if res.Error != nil {
            fmt.Printf("ERR: No se ha podido consultar el poste %d\n", res.Number)
            fmt.Printf("Detalles del error: %v\n", res.Error)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Poste: %4d (%3d)\n", res.Number, res.StatusCode)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    start := time.Now()

    var (
        wg  sync.WaitGroup
        in  = make(chan Work)
        out = make(chan Result)
    )

    const (
        NumWorkers  = 15
        TotalPostes = 1500
    )

    // Por defecto el cliente HTTP de Go tiene un timeout infinito así que
    // (casi) siempre es mejor definir uno nuevo con un timeout más razonable.
    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 5,
    }

    // Paso 1: Arrancar al menos un worker
    wg.Add(NumWorkers)
    for w := 0; w < NumWorkers; w++ {
        go worker(&wg, in, out) // el WaitGroup hay que pasarlo por referencia!
    }

    // Paso 2a: Utilizar los resultados (IMPORTANTE: llegarán desordenados, seguramente)
    go consumir(out)

    // Paso 2b: Enviar trabajo al worker(s)
    for p := 0; p < TotalPostes; p++ {
        in <- Work{Client: client, Number: p}
    }

    // IMPORTANTE: cerrar el canal de "entrada" de los workers para que puedan
    // acabar su trabajo de manera limpia. En la función "worker" usamos un
    // bucle que lee del canal, al cerrar el canal el bucle se acaba por lo que
    // "worker" acaba llamando al método "Done" del "WaitGroup".
    close(in)

    // Paso 3: Esperar a que todos los workers hayan terminado su trabajo
    wg.Wait()

    // IMPORTANTE: cerrar el canal de "salida" de los workers para que la
    // función "consumir" termine de manera limpia.
    //
    // En Go es muy fácil tener leaks de goroutinas, interesa ser muy explícito
    // con sus ciclos de vida.
    close(out)

    // Paso 4: Mostrar resultados del programa
    fmt.Printf("Consultadas %d paradas en %s\n", TotalPostes, time.Since(start))
}
```